# How to compile NestJS to ESM distribution file?

Tags: typescript, webpack, nestjs

I am using the base application of NestJS, the boilerplate NestJS suggest. I just try to configure NestJS to compile my code to ESM main.js file.

I configured my TSConfig with those keys:

```json
        "target": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
        "module": "ESNext",
```

and my `package.json` file includes `"type": "module"`

And I configured `nest-cli.json`:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
    "sourceRoot": "./src",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "webpack": true,
        "deleteOutDir": true
    }
}
```

I run NestJS using `"start:dev": "dotenv -e ./envs/.env.development -- nest build --webpackPath webpack.config.dev.cjs --watch",`

I tried to follow NestJS article for hot module reload: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload

And I configured my Webpack file as:

```js
const path = require('node:path');

const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const { RunScriptWebpackPlugin } = require('run-script-webpack-plugin');

/**
 * @type { import('webpack').Configuration }
 */
const configuration = (options, webpack) => ({
    ...options,
    entry: ['webpack/hot/poll?100', options.entry],
    externals: [
        nodeExternals({
            allowlist: ['webpack/hot/poll?100'],
            modulesDir: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            importType: (moduleName) => `import ${moduleName}`,
        }),
    ],
    experiments: { outputModule: true },
    plugins: [
        ...options.plugins,
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin({
            paths: [/\.d\.ts$/],
        }),
        new RunScriptWebpackPlugin({ name: options.output.filename, autoRestart: false }),
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: { type: 'module' },
        chunkFormat: 'module',
    },
});

module.exports = configuration;
```

When  I run it I don't get errors, but I get instant message every second: [HMR] Nothing hot updated.
It repeats itself infinitely. Where am I wrong?